# Get average time of creating hibernate entity

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have some complex Entity classes with `@Formula`, `@OneToMany` relations, and i need to monitor time that is spent on **sql** query and creating entity instance.

Something similar on but for entity,
`org.hibernate.stat.QueryStatistics.getExecutionAvgTime()`
,

Maybe library have any standard metric, but I did not find them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Hibernate JConsole plugin which provides all the statics of hibernate

[JConsole plugin](http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/)

Also look at this once [Monitoring a SessionFactory of Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-monitoring)

There is one another option [Craftsman Spy JDBC Driver 1.0.5](http://zer0.free.fr/craftsman/spy.php)

Craftsman Spy is an open source and free framework for JDBC logging. It is a JDBC driver implementation.

- This logger logs all SQL connection and processings with execution spent time, all the stored procedures with arguments, all the batch processings and the result sets.
- No need to modify your application in order to integrate JDBC logging with Craftsman Spy. The application MUST use the craftsman.spy.SpyDriver and MUST be launched with the -Dspy.driver=... system property.

`Be carefull this JDBC driver SHOULD not be used in production mode. Use it only in  development or pre-production system.`

Comment: I suggest JConsole. For me JConsole is the best option.